# Excel - calculation input from either of 2 cells will calculate the other

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have to use this several times with different scenarios. So i will give an example  hoping i can recycle the code elsewhere.  i need to calculate the diameter or height of a cylinder (for use elsewhere on the page) the 2 cells are in 1 column  E17, E18. entering data in 1 should calculate the other  (as height and diameter are related through the volume in E16).  hoping i don't need macros as i  am a newb there.

Comment: Do you want the volumn to be constant ?

Comment: An example would help, as you can't have both a formula in a cell.   I would look into using an entry cell so it tell Excel if you trying to calculate the value for E17 or E18.  You could us an overall IF(ISFORMULA) in both cells E17 and E18 pointing at each other then when you enter a value in one the other perform the calculation, but once you add the value in one the formula is no longer in that cell.

Comment: Please note: Excel has **either** pure data **OR** a formula in a cell.

Comment: The volume with be the an input variable from which H/R is derived from using R/H as the the 2nd variable required to solve the equation(s) - 1 per.H/R cell.

Answer (score 1):

Enter your diameter in **A2** and the cylinder height in **B2**.  In **C2** enter the formula for the cylinder volume:

```
=B2*PI()*(A2/2)^2
```

Then copy **C2** and PasteSpecialValues back onto itself:

[image]

Finally place the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A2 As Range, B2 As Range, A2B2 As Range
    Dim Intersection As Range, C2 As Range
    Dim pie As Double
    
    pie = WorksheetFunction.Pi()
    Set A2 = Range("A2")
    Set B2 = Range("B2")
    Set C2 = Range("C2")
    Set A2B2 = Range("A2:B2")
    Set Intersection = Intersect(Target, A2B2)
    
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersection Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value <= 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Target.Address(0, 0) = "A2" Then
            B2.Value = C2.Value / (pie * (A2.Value / 2) ^ 2)
        Else
            A2.Value = 2# * ((C2.Value / B2.Value) / pie) ^ 0.5
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
            
End Sub
```

If you change **A2**, then **B2** will adjust.
If you change **B2**, then **A2** will adjust.
If you change **C2**, nothing will happen immediately, but future changes to either **A2** or **B2** will re-calculate the other against the new value for the volume.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to **install** and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**